# Notation for "Statement" and comparing "Suppose $P$" with "Suppose $P$ is true"

Tags: notation

1. What are the common notations for the purpose of denoting that a sentence is a statement? For example, how do I say "Let P be a statement (notation start) x=1 (notation end)". I have seen "x=1" and [x=1], but I would like to get to know about this more.
2. I will assume that "P" is the notation for the purpose of denoting that the sentence P is a statement. How would we compare suppose P with suppose P is true? I think the former is just an abbreviation of the latter expression, but I would like to be clear.

Comment: The convention $[\text{statement}]$ is called the Iverson bracket, and is one way to write an indicator-type function. I don't think, however, there is a standard way to use symbols to say "Suppose P is true." It's better, in my opinion, to just say what you need without using symbols for uncommon things.

Comment: As far as I could look up in couple of minutes, Iverson bracket is a map that takes a statement with variables to 0 and 1 corresponding to its truth value being false and true, respectively. However, you are saying this is used as a convention with no relation to this defintion just to indicate function, i.e. forget its value? Also, question 2 is considered for starting a proof. If I want to show that $P\implies Q$, should I start with "Suppose $P$." or "Suppose $P$ is true?"

Comment: I'm saying there's no "standard." I say both at times, but lean towards the latter for your second part.

Comment: I think the question of when native speakers of English add "is true" is primarily a linguistics question, not a math one. "Suppose that 'clouds are green'." is a valid English sentence. And eliding "that" would be fine, too. Adding "is true" isn't necessary, but might be done rarely. I don't know which contexts would make it more likely to be used, so am not posting an answer about it